# How can I get Itunes on Mac to see all of my music?

Tags: itunes

I setup itunes on a new mac and downloaded all of my purchases songs.  I now copied all of my music from an external hard drive onto the directory:

```
 Music/Itunes Media/Music
```

I then restart Itunes but it doesn't recognize any of the new music that I just copied over.

What is the best way for itunes to detect all of this new music?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunes uses an internal database for your song list. Move the songs you added manually from Finder to the Desktop (for example).

Check in iTunes settings that it's set to let iTunes manage the Music Library.

Open iTunes and drag and drop the song folder on iTunes (either the window or the icon in the Dock).

iTunes will then copy them and add them to its library.

You can now delete the songs you have on your Desktop.